# Aligning items in cardview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

I want my card to look like the following

[image]

I kept my layout like this

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order# GAMH2103"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Confirmed"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/check"
                android:textColor="#00FF00"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textSize="15dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Somehow, i am not able to get the "confirmed" TextView visible. I can see the order# though.

I have played with the `gravity` and `layout_gravity` but somehow couldn't get through.

Please help.

Thanks, Lakshman.

Comment: Because you set width the  "order# though" TextView `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, so the "confirmed" TextView can't visible. Change to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. You can add `android:layout_weight="1"` if you want the "confirmed" TextView allways visible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the following layout.This will work for you.

It is always preferred to use Relative Layout instead of Linear layout for better view alignment .

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order# GAMH2103"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Confirmed"
            android:textColor="#00FF00"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple relative layout should do the job.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Order# GAMH2103"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirmed"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/check"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note the difference between `gravity` and `layout_gravity`, if you use `gravity` in a `TextView`, it pertains to the position of the text inside the **invisible box** that is the border of `TextView`, so for example, `layout_gravity` on the other hand pertains to the position of the view inside the parent.