# Aligning TextView in CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm trying to align multiple TextView items in a CardView. I'm going to use this CardView in my RecyclerView to display data. But this doesn't work for all screen size. First I'm showing some static labels and then a CardView to show real data. Below is the code for my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:text="P"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="W"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.073"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView12"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="L"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.084"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView13"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="D"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.112"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView14"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:text="GD"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.092"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView15"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Pts"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView16"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wisdom High"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/table_team_name"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
        android:id="@+id/played"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
        android:id="@+id/won"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
        android:id="@+id/lost"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:id="@+id/draw"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+12"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:id="@+id/gd"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
        android:id="@+id/points"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It doesn't work for all screen sizes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aligning items in cardview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169090/aligning-items-in-cardview)

Comment: @Mr.Roshan My card view has multiple items and the other question has only two. I'm unable to align multiple textview items in my card view. I works for some screen size but not for all

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? Please explain what you currently have and what is your expected result. Also, please include full layout with root tag.

Comment: @plaskoff The alignment is perfect for some screen size like 5 inches, but when I run the activity on a larger screen like 6 inches it doesnt align as expected :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always preferred to use Relative Layout for better view alignment .

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/table_team_name"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wisdom High"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/played"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/won"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/draw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
            android:text="+12"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

for multiple screens [For Text Size](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) and [For Dimenions](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Answer (score 2):

1. Avoid using hard coded layout sizes.
2. Use RelativeLayout inside the CardView

Answer (score 1):

[prashant-luhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7003439/prashant-luhar), you can use sth like this: (for every screen size with 'layout-weight' property)

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#888"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="P"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="W"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="L"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="GD"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Pts"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="A"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="P1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="W1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="L"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="GD"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Pts"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="B"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="P2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="W2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="L"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="GD"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Pts"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="C"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="P3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="W3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="L"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="GD"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Pts"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="P4"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="W4"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="L"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="GD"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Pts"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="E"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="P5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="W5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="L"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="GD"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Pts"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="F"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="P6"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="W6"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="L"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="D"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="GD"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Pts"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```